# Running git commands from within a PHP script

Tags: php, git

I have a file upload form and after the file uploads I want to push the files up to GitHub by running:

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push origin master
```

How do I go about this? I've seen examples of using `exec()` but that makes me nervous.

```
shell_exec('cd /var/www/vhost/xxx.com/httpdocs/clients/portal/upoads/54 && /usr/bin/git add -A');
shell_exec('cd /var/www/vhost/xxx.com/httpdocs/clients/portal/upoads/54 && /usr/bin/git commit -m "something 1"');
shell_exec('cd /var/www/vhost/xxx.com/httpdocs/clients/portal/upoads/54 && /usr/bin/git push origin master');
```

Those commands don't error but don't work either. Do I need to grant access to the apache user to use the ssh key?

Comment: Have you looked at [PHP GitHub API](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api)?

Comment: CentOS - yes I looked at that library but I am using CodeIgniter 3 and not using composer, so I wasn't sure how to implement it.

Comment: I tried this too: https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php

Comment: I split it into two libraries and put them in /libraries inside codeigniter and loaded them successfully with $this->load->library() but when I told it my github repo path it either said it didn't exist or wasn't a git repo, but it is, I initialized it.

Comment: I got this library to run:  https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php and I got the error "Message: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." -- so it is a permission error, how do I give my web user access to the known hosts and key?

Comment: I can cd into that directory from the CLI and do a commit, as root, on my server.

Answer (score 2):

i guess is permission problems, you can use exec() , and get the error info by $output

```
exec($your_command.' 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I ran this: $your_command = 'cd /var/www/vhost/xxx.com/httpdocs/clients/portal/upoads/54 && /usr/bin/git status';
        exec($your_command.' 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
        var_dump($output);

Comment: I got this:  array(0) { }

Comment: just run your command,what you get：cd /var/www/vhost/xxx.com/httpdocs/clients/portal/upoads/54 && /usr/bin/git status

Comment: Nothing, just an empty page

Comment: If I run it at the command line it just says repo clean... I just need to add access for my web user to the ssh key but I have no idea how. I tried generating a new key inside it's home directory / .ssh and adding that to github but that didn't worth either.

Comment: i guess,you need change to web user like 'sudo su - apache' ,then generate a ssh key in ~/.ssh(not /.ssh) and add to github?

Comment: I did that, I created it as root, added it to github, I still get the error.

Comment: But I chowned it too sudo chown -R apache:apache ~apache/.ssh

Comment: root and apache ,has different home path ,you'd better to switch to apache to do that...

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to grant access to the apache user to use the ssh key?

**Yes**.

This means you have to **copy** the key somewhere that the `apache` user can read it.  SSH won't work unless the key file is readable by the user only (i.e. `0600` permissions on the key file).

Copy the key like:

```bash
mkdir -p --mode=0700 ~apache/.ssh    
cp /my/id_rsa ~apache/.ssh/id_rsa
chown -R apache:apache ~apache/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 ~apache/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Also, you don't need to `cd` every time you want to run the command. Use `GIT_DIR`:

```php
putenv('GIT_DIR=/path/to/git/repo')
shell_exec('git commit ...')
```

Comment: I am still getting the error: "Message: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Comment: Grisha, if I run exec('whoami') inside of my PHP script I get 'opcode' and when I cat /etc/passwd I see that opcode's home directory is /var/www/vhost/xxx.com so I created a .ssh directory in there and moved the files in and applied the permissions you suggested, I chowned it to opcode:psacln to match the script... no luck.

Comment: Any ideas? There has to be a way LOL.

Comment: You can debug by running `su -s /bin/bash opcode` to start a shell as the web server user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I ran all of this as root user.

Inside my PHP script I ran

```
exec("whoami");
```

to get the user that is running that script. Then I ran

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

to get the home directory for that user (/var/www/vhost/mydomain.com)

I noticed that on my web server (Centos 7) that all my web files were chown'd as opcode:psacln so I created a .ssh directory inside opcode's home folder:

```
mkdir -p --mode=0700 /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh  
cd (back to root)  
cp .ssh/id_rsa /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh/id_rsa
chown -R opcode:psacln /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The thing I was missing was that I had to also move my known_hosts file over, since the script I was using wasn't adding to it.

```
cp .ssh/known_hosts /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 0600 /var/www/vhost/mydomain.com/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Of course, I had to login to my server at the command line and do an initial commit to the repo in order to get it added to my known_hosts file, before I copied it over. Hope this helps someone.